# Eclipse (2019-06) PMD 4.6.0 plugin import ruleset grayed out OK button

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I've installed the PMD plugin (4.6.0) into the latest version of Eclipse (2019-06),
but when I try to import a ruleset the OK button remains grayed out.

I've already deleted all of the defualt rules.

How can I import my ruleset?